# Wrapped GtkLabel huge height

Tags: gtk3

```
auto widget=gtk_label_new(text);
m_handle=GTK_LABEL(widget);
gtk_label_set_line_wrap(m_handle,TRUE);
gtk_label_set_max_width_chars(m_handle,80);
gtk_widget_set_size_request(GTK_WIDGET(m_handle),-1,1);
```

And, the label wraps but GTK thinks the widget require the height equal to line break after every word. And no, I cannot shrink the window manually. How to restore its height?

[image: A huge window]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I'm not at all experienced with Gtk3 programming, I have seen a very similar phenomenon in Qt5.

I think what happens is that Gtk3 will set the minimum height of the label to the height it would have when wrapped to its minimum width. I mean the minimum width of the label itself, so even if the window cannot be made smaller, the label could potentially, if there were some other widgets next to it in the window.

This mechanism is described here: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#geometry-management

Note especially:

> The minimum height for the minimum width is normally used to set the
>   minimum size constraint on the toplevel (unless
>   gtk_window_set_geometry_hints() is explicitly used instead).

So you could try setting a bigger minimum width constraint on the label itself, and see if that changes anything.

Comment: for anyone reading, the above comment basically means to use the gtk_widget_set_size_request(label, width, height) function to manually set the size of the text rather than letting GTK overestimate the size drastically. More info at https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.Widget.set_size_request.html

Answer (score 1):

Best working solution for me so far (gtkmm):

```cpp
class MultiLineLabel : public Gtk::Label {
public:
    MultiLineLabel() : Gtk::Label() {
        #if GTKMM_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
        set_line_wrap();
        #endif
    }

    void set_markup(const Glib::ustring& s) {
        Gtk::Label::set_markup(s);
        m_markup = s;
    }

    void get_preferred_height_for_width_vfunc(int width, int& minimum_height, int& natural_height) const {
        Gtk::Label::get_preferred_height_for_width_vfunc(width, minimum_height, natural_height);

        Pango::Layout* origLayout = const_cast<Pango::Layout*>(get_layout().operator->());
        Glib::RefPtr<Pango::Layout> layout = origLayout->copy();
        Glib::ustring s = (!m_markup.empty()) ? m_markup : get_text();
        layout->set_markup(s);
        int w, h;
        layout->get_pixel_size(w, h);
        h += get_margin_top() + get_margin_bottom();

        minimum_height = h;
        if (natural_height < h)
            natural_height = h;
    }

private:
    Glib::ustring m_markup;
};
```

This solution overrides `get_preferred_height_for_width_vfunc()` and uses the label's current layout settings and current text (or markup) to calculate the exact width and height for that text required for rendering it on screen.

Other suggestions I found on the net so far, did not work for me. For instance the [gtk docs suggest](https://developer.gnome.org/Labels/#Labels_in_resizable_windows) using `gtk_label_set_width_chars(GTK_LABEL(label), 30)`, but that just reduces the wasted height a bit, it does not fix the problem. So if the text goes over more than couple lines, you will still have plenty of vertical space wasted when using `gtk_label_set_width_chars(GTK_LABEL(label), 30)`. Calling `gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(win), x, -1);` did not make any difference to me.